# iphone showing strange dates in all apps

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios

This issue is being faced since quite a while on my iPhone 5c since iOS 9 upgrade. All the dates wherever applicable are getting displayed are something not-in-human understandable format. I tried complete restore, waited for updates till 9.3, also have asked for apple authorized service center. None helped. They said, its not a product fault.
Attaching screenshots. these screenshots are old, but the issue still presists.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: In Settings > General > Languages & Region, what do you have the Region & Calendar option set to? Being in the US, I have Gregorian selected, with Japanese and Buddhist as options. Make sure your iPhone is set for the correct region, then select another non-Gregorian calendar format, then select Gregorian again. What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search into your issue shows you may have your Calendar set as "Buddhist".

You can check this and change that setting by going to the Settings app -> General -> Language & Region -> Scroll down to Region Formats -> Tap Calendar -> Make sure it's set to Gregorian.

Try that and see if that fixes it?

Answer found here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4679590?tstart=0